# Unusual positive sign in price sensitivity in a Generalized Bass Model in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement the Generalized Bass Model (GBM) in R with price as a decision variable. Price is decreasing and product adoption is increasing through the years in my dataset. However, I am finding the price sensitivity (alpha) sign as positive in my estimations which is strange because in the literature, the authors find it negative as in (see in [Kurdgelashvili et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040162517309307?via%3Dihub)). My scaling function is the following as in [Kurdgelashvili et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040162517309307?via%3Dihub):

```
T + alpha * ln(P(t)/P(0))
```

where T is the number of years since the initial adoption, P(t) is the price at instant t and P(0) is the price at instant when product adoption begins.
Then, I am implementing the GBM in R as follows:

```
F(t) = (1 - exp(-(p + q) * (T + alpha * ln(P(t)/P(0)))))/(1 + q / p *exp(- (p + q) * (T + alpha * ln(P(t)/P(0)))))
```

where F(t) is the cumulative adoption rate, p and q are the innovation and imitation coefficients, respectively (see [Krishnan et al](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2634783)).

Is this GBM right or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting some experienced researchers, they told me that in fact my model was suffering from the omitted variable bias and I should use other decision variables. Indeed, when I added other variables, the coeficients signs were as expected.